# casting object array to another array having class instance

Tags: java, casting

```
Class<?> class = ...
Object[] objects = ...
```

Is there any nice and fast way to cast array of Objects to destination type having only class instance representing destination array objects type. 
There is class.cast(Object ob) function but that way I have to create new array and iterate over each object

Comment: A cast does not change the type of an object.

Comment: And if it's only about casting: Yes, you'll have to create new array and iterate.